# Accounting table design for outstanding balances by due days (0-30,31-60, etc)

Tags: sql, finance, account, accounting

I have an accounting transaction table with the following fields:

- transactionid
- date
- transactiontype (charge,payment,credit,etc)
- debitaccount
- creditaccount
- amount

And I have the following records

```
id  date         type     debaccount   credaccount   amount
--  ----------   -------  ----------   -----------   ------
1   02/13/2012   charge   utilities    receivables   $200.00
2   02/17/2012   charge   maintenan    receivables   $150.00
3   03/06/2012   credit   receivables  utilities     ($20.00)
4   03/27/2012   charge   repairs      receivables   $80.00
5   04/29/2012   charge   utilities    receivables   $135.00
6   05/21/2012   charge   utilities    receivables   $70.00
7   06/22/2012   charge   utilities    receivables   $60.00
8   07/19/2012   payment  receivables  utilities     ($100.00)
```

Right now I can get the balance without problem, so I know:

Account Utilities Income 
200-20(credit)+135+70+60 = 445 - 100 (payment) = Balance $345

Now what I need is to get the outstanding balance by due days for example:

```
Account      0-30 days   31-60 days  61-90 days   90+ days    Balance
---------    ---------   ----------  ----------   ---------   ----------
receivables  $60.00      $70.00      $135.00      $200.00     $465.00
                                                  ($20)       $445.00
                                                  ($100)      $345.00
```

I have seen that when you have an outstanding balance, if you make a payment, that payment will be affecting the very last charge (as seen in the table). My question is if I need to have a relation between transactions and transactions so I will know that one payment is affecting "x" number of charges. This is the only solution it came into my mind in order to get the desired outstanding balance by due days.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using excel 2010, then you can use **"sumifs"** function.

You can check the dummy solution.

test.xlsx

[URL=http://www.4shared.com/file/bVIFy_X8/test.html]test.xlsx[/URL]